# Reading from the clipboard with Swift 3 on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nspasteboard

I'm a beginner with Swift, and I'm trying to figure out how can I read what has been copied to the clipboard On macOS (Swift 3)? I've searched a lot but can't seem to find anything that works.

A few of the things I've tried from online:

```
var pasteboardItems: [NSPasteboardItem]? { get }
print("\(pasteboardItems)")
```

and

```
let pb = NSPasteboard.general()
pb.string(forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)

print("\(pb)")
```

and

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
if let string = pasteboard.string {
    // text was found and placed in the "string" constant
}
```

and lastly

```
func paste(sender: AnyObject?) {

    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()

    if let nofElements = pasteboard.pasteboardItems?.count {

        if nofElements > 0 {


            // Assume they are strings

            var strArr: Array<String> = []
            for element in pasteboard.pasteboardItems! {
                if let str = element.stringForType("public.utf8-plain-text") {
                    strArr.append(str)
                }
            }


            // Exit if no string was read

            if strArr.count == 0 { return }


            // Perform the paste operation

            dataSource.cmdPaste(strArr)
       }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd code is the only attempt in the right direction. The 3rd is for iOS. The 4th is Swift 2. The 1st makes no sense.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Works for **Swift 3** and **Swift 4**

```
// Set string to clipboard
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string], owner: nil)
pasteboard.setString("Good Morning", forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)

var clipboardItems: [String] = []
for element in pasteboard.pasteboardItems! {
    if let str = element.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "public.utf8-plain-text")) {
        clipboardItems.append(str)
    }
}

// Access the item in the clipboard
let firstClipboardItem = clipboardItems[0] // Good Morning
```

Comment: Yeah, glad that I could help you!

Comment: `clipboardItems` is empty for me.

Answer (score 6):

Times have changed. In Swift 3+ you would do it like this: (if you are only interested in strings)

```
func clipboardContent() -> String?
{
    return NSPasteboard.general.pasteboardItems?.first?.string(forType: .string)
}
```

Comment: At least in Swift 5, no need for `.pasteboardItems?.first?`, this works: `NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string)`.

Answer (score 6):

Another Swift 4 Solution

```
// Write to pasteboard
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string], owner: nil)
pasteboard.setString("Good Morning", forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)

// Read from pasteboard
let read = pasteboard.pasteboardItems?.first?.string(forType: .string)
```

Comment: Swift 5: `'NSPasteboardType' has been renamed to NSPasteboard.PasteboardType'` .

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```
class ViewController : NSViewController {

  @IBAction func pasteMenuItemAction(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let p = NSPasteboard.general
    let x = p.readObjects(forClasses: [NSString.self], options: nil)
    let s = x as! [NSString]
    if 0 < s.count {
      print(s[0])
    }
  }

}
```

That func `pasteMenuItemAction()` is bound to an Edit > Paste menu item.

I use `writeObjects()` for Edit > Copy. So it is natural for me to use its counterpart `readObjects()` here.

Confirmed with Xcode 9.2, Swift 4

**Added:**

One of the solutions for Edit > Copy:

```
  @IBAction func copyMenuItemAction(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let t = "Hello!"
    let p = NSPasteboard.general
    p.clearContents()
    p.writeObjects([t as NSPasteboardWriting])
  }
```

That func `copyMenuItemAction()` is bound to an Edit > Copy menu item.

Answer (score -1):

Easier ✅     **Swift 4:**

```
@IBAction func pasteAction(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let stringToPaste: String = UIPasteboard.general.items.last?.first?.value as? String else { return }
    MYTEXTVIEW.text = stringToPaste
}
```